# Problema proxy al realizar una peticion

Tags: python, linux

Estoy intentando ejecutar un archivo de python en la terminal de linux 16.04, el cual contiene peticiones de la API de Google drive y me aparece el siguiente problema:

```
py", line 1531, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at oauth2.googleapis.com
```

investigue un poco y es problemas de proxy y lo solucione poniendo los siguientes comandos la terminal:

```
export http_proxy=
export https_proxy=
```

El problema esta que al abrir una nueva terminal tengo que volver a poner los comandos anteriores, existe algún archivo del sistema que pueda modificar para que esa configuración quede permanente?.

Gracias.

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo se puede configurar mediante  el archivo `/etc/environment`  (variables de entorno ), pero obviamente esto tiene repercusiones globales.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por tu ayuda.